# Can I have a non-SharePoint portal for TFS?

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

I find SharePoint (WSS 3) portal messy to use & manage with TFS. I want to use the Scrum template and have access to all reports that are required, but without SharePoint. Is there any other mechanism to provide a portal fabric on the TFS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need SharePoint to be installed to view the Reports (except if you're talking about Excel Services Reports, but there're few of them).
The Reports folder in Team Explorer will display the reports you need, and the SQL Reporting Service Web site too.

Comment: Thanks Nock. I will check this approach's overall suitability and update you.

Answer (score 4):

On the `Team Settings` > `Portal Settings` you can set any website as the team portal which will be opened on the `Show Project Portal` option.
[image: portal]